# How to create a custom collectionview layout like the image below

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am trying to create something like this in the image [image: layout] I have achieved the columns but the part i am finding hard is how to lift right column higher than the left one.

Comment: This might be helpful: https://www.donnywals.com/creating-a-custom-uicollectionviewlayout-in-swift/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use your own UICollectionViewLayout class and do your customizations acheive this type of view.This is basically adding offsetY for each alternating cell.

Comment: I have done something similar.You can check here: https://github.com/AhsanMughal10/Custom-OffsetY-Cells-CollectionView.git

Comment: Thanks that worked exactly the way i wanted.

Comment: Happy to know that :)